# jquery UI slider with tooltip

Tags: jquery-ui, slider

I have a jquery UI slider on a webpage I'm working on, but I'm looking to get a tooltip on the slider too.  I've been through most of the questions here (searching) and didn't find what I was looking for or I couldn't understand the answer(s).

Here's a sample of what I'm looking for:
[Sample UI Slider with tooltip](http://media02.hongkiat.com/jquery-ui-slider/demo/index.html)

Here is my slider:
[My slider with no tooltip yet](http://mypaydayloanus.com/)

I just created a simple UI slider from the jquery website.  Snap to increments.  Ideally, whatever dollar amount the slider is on, I'd like the tooltip to display right above it.  I'll tackle CSS code later for look n' feel.

and I can't post my actual code, because it has hyperlinks in it, and because I'm a newbie here, this website won't let me make a posting with more than 2 hyperlinks, which I've already used up to show you the sample and my slider.

Comment: The answer for your question is in it itself!!!

Comment: Using jQuery UI Tooltip.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are looking for [this](http://css-tricks.com/value-bubbles-for-range-inputs/).

Basically, this tutorial shows how to style the slider and place a tooltip above the slider to get the value of the input.

Comment: One could use a jQuery Tooltip rather than pure javascript as in your example.