# Jquery Range slider with tooltip

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using Jquery Ui with range slider (2 handles on sliders) to filter minimum and maximum values. However, any idea how to add tooltip for both handle, since the slider itself does not support tooltip with slider.

Comment: could you provide a jsfiddle?

Comment: possible duplicate of [jquery UI slider with tooltip](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14088408/jquery-ui-slider-with-tooltip)

Comment: the requirement for slider is using jquery ui, where html5 slider might not work for some of the browsers.... the jquery ui slider is something like this... but with tooltip http://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/slider/range.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the slider has been loaded you could simply create a tooltip widget on the handles

```
$('.ui-slider-handle').tooltip();
```

Comment: loaded? you meant after the jquery ui slider initialized?

Comment: loaded and initialised is te same

Answer (score 1):

`.ui-slider-handle` class has two items when used as a range. Therefore you must use `.first()` and `.last()` methods properly in order to get min and max range handlers.

Here is the [jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/b6tux4we/).

This is the modified version of the answer of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11192442/jqueryui-slider-tooltip-for-the-current-position):

```
    var tooltipmin = $('<div id="tooltip" />').css({
    position: 'absolute',
    top: -25,
    left: -10
}).hide();
var tooltipmax = $('<div id="tooltip" />').css({
    position: 'absolute',
    top: -25,
    left: -10
}).hide();
var slideritem = $("#slider").slider({
    values: [350, 500],
    min: 0,
    max: 1000,
    step: 50,
    range: true,
    slide: function(event, ui) {
        tooltipmin.text(ui.values[0]);
        tooltipmax.text(ui.values[1]);
    },
    change: function(event, ui) {
        tooltipmin.text(ui.values[0]);
        tooltipmax.text(ui.values[1]);
    }
});
slideritem
    .find(".ui-slider-handle")
    .first()
    .append(tooltipmin)
    .hover(function() {
        tooltipmin.show();
        tooltipmax.show();
    }, function() {
        tooltipmin.hide();
        tooltipmax.hide();
    });
slideritem
    .find(".ui-slider-handle")
    .last()
    .append(tooltipmax)
    .hover(function() {
        tooltipmin.show();
        tooltipmax.show();
    }, function() {
        tooltipmin.hide();
        tooltipmax.hide();
    });
```